# Laravel migrations won't apply on MySQL (InnoDB)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, centos, innodb

**Hello everyone,**

This is my first time posting !

I am running into a problem when applying **laravel 8** migrations on my new web server.
While trying to deploy my projet I'm unable to apply migrations and I'm not sure why.

Below **images of the error and my migration**, i'm using the `php artisan migrate --seed` command

Outputed message when migrating:
[image: Outputed message when migrating]

My migration with foreign keys:
[image]

The problem seems to be associated with the foreign key constraints but it's maybe because of something else. My server is running MySQL on InnoDB so **I'm suspecting a compatibility problem**, still, I have no clue how to solve it.

**I tried:**

- Applying migrations one by one so that constraints would reference already existing foreign keys. Didn't work
- Changing my engine to InnoDB in config/database.php. Didn't work
- Importing my database manually using command line. Didn't work
- Adding DB_ENGINE = InnoDB to the .env file. Didn't work
- Switching from `$table->foreign('idUser')->references('id')->on('users');`

  to `$table->foreignId('idUser')->nullable->constrained();`

**My server**

- Centos 7
- MySQL - InnoDB
- PHP 7.4
- Has Cpanel

Also, I have **no problem applying the migrations on localhost**, whitch leads me to believe this is not a problem with the structure of the migrations...

I am running out of ideas and can't seem to find a good awnser on the internet. Can someone help me ? Also please let me know if i forgot to provide important information

Comment: Looks like you're referencing a table that doesn't exist yet. Also make sure the types of columns are the same for foreign keys and their references (unsigned, biginteger, nullable etc)

Comment: As I said, I've tried applying migrations in the right order. This can't be the problem...

Comment: Check if length and type of primary key of parent table and this migration is same.

Comment: @FaizanAli I tried using the $table->foreignId('idUser')->constrained() method which should prevent such problems but the result is the same unfortunatly

Comment: Where does `idRoles` appear in your migrations? The file you posted seem unrelated to the error!?

Comment: @brombeer Sorry I uploaded the wrong migration, but its now fixed

Comment: From your first image it seems that the `users` table is the only table that's been created. No `roles` or `kits` table seems to exist that could be referenced

Comment: That's because the migration was the first to apply so as soon as it opened it, the problem surged, but i tried applying them in the right order as well !

Comment: Either rename your files (the "date" part) so your `users` table including foreign keys gets created _after_ your `kits` and `roles` tables. Or split your `users` migration into two files, one that creates the table, then create the `kits` and `roles` tables, _then_ another migration that creates the foreign keys. You cannot reference a table that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @brombeer I've updated the image so you can see what I mean. I already tried to rename the files and migrations are applying in the right order. The table roles and kits already exist when the migration fails

Comment: That makes more sense now that you've renamed the file. Now make sure the types of columns are the exact same. What does your `roles` migration look like? Why has the error message changed?

Comment: `roles` only containes `$table->id();`  and `$table->string('name', 15)->nullable();`. But when referencing it with `$table->foreignId` didn't work either and the method automaticly uses the right type

Comment: `->id()` is an alias of `bigIncrements()` (as stated in https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-id). `bigIncrements()` in turn creates an auto-incrementing UNSIGNED BIGINT. Your `idRole` column is an _integer_ field only. As mentioned multiple times, make sure the types of the columns are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in fact with the way I wrote my migrations, if someone else has this problem, you can find a good awnser here: [laravel-8-foreign-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66309431/laravel-8-foreign-key)

Thank you @brombeer for helping me !